# Scrolling Header resizing improperly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with an issue we are having with our site.  The person that originally did the site is no longer with us and I'm not that familiar with javascript/jquery so I don't know where to begin to look.

Our site is http://new.onlinehc.com

When the page loads, there is a header bar that stays at the top as the user scrolls down the page.  You will notice that **before** scrolling, the header is correct:
[image]

But if you scroll down to the bottom and back up to the top, you will notice the header bar's height changes for some reason, making it bigger, cutting off part of the image in the blue banner:
[image]

If anyone can help me out and tell me why this is changing and how I can possibly fix it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly sifted through the source of your website and I found a line in the function `scrollPage()` in [`script.js`](http://new.onlinehc.com/Content/js/script.js) that I think is causing the problem:

```
$('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top': 19 + "px", 'padding-bottom': 19 + "px" });
```

This is just a hunch, though. You will have to investigate further by changing the value.

When the web page is scrolled past a certain point, the above line is called, changing the padding around the logo.

When I went into Chrome dev tools and scrolled the page, I noticed a uniform padding around the top and bottom of the element that looked like this, further indicating that it might be caused by that padding value:

[image: Padding around the .navbar-brand element]

Comment: I think you're right, remove padding-top or change the padding-top attribute for the element posted above and the issue seems to be solved

Comment: You are correct sir....doing the same thing as ctwheels and it resolved the problem.  Thanks a bunch!